# Need to get SUM of SubQuery

Tags: mysql

My query listed below, returns correctly a list of numbers = Count(ID) AS `Antal`. But now I need to `SUM(Antal)` - how to do that?

I have tried to wrap the query as a two subqueries, but still can't get the sum of `Antal`. What to do ? :-)

```
 SELECT Field1, Field2,COUNT(ID) AS "Antal" FROM FlexStat
 WHERE Field2 IN (SELECT Field2 FROM FlexStat WHERE LENGTH(Field3) = 0 AND Field2 <> 'anonymt' AND Field1 = '2007')
 AND
     Field1 = 2007
 AND 
     LENGTH(Field3) = 0
 GROUP BY Field2;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap an outer query and use the query you wrote as an inner query. Try:

```
SELECT SUM(Antal) FROM (<your-query>);
```